# List of Buttons lighting up at random

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uianimation

The method im trying to achieve is set a button to 0.5 alpha then back to 1 in the space of three seconds. After its executed 5 time on the four buttons the block of code is finished. Im struggling to find a way in which this can be achieved becasue right now the block below will be an infinite loop when i want it to be only executed through once.

```
int rand=random()%5;

switch (rand) {
    case 1:{            

        [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
        [btnYellow setAlpha:0.5];
        [btnYellow setAlpha:1];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
        break;

    case 2:
        [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0]; 

        [btnRed setAlpha:0.5];

        [btnRed setAlpha:1];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        break;

    case 3:

        [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0]; 
        [btnBlue setAlpha:1];

        [UIView commitAnimations];

    case 4:

        [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0]; 
        [btnGreen setAlpha:1];

        [UIView commitAnimations]; 
        break;

    case 5:

        [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
        [btnYellow setAlpha:1];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        break;

}
```

Comment: `rand` can never be `5`, but there's nothing that looks like an infinite loop anywhere in that code.

Comment: Ive called this method which must have been where that problem is . but still the effect wont work when i use this code it will stay the same colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've been using this site for several years, and I was due for a nice thorough answer to give back.

I built [a project](https://github.com/rynwola/FadeButtons) and accomplished the functionality you desired. Some notes:

-The key is recursion! You need to animate the fade out (using the function I provided) and, upon completion, animating the fade back in using the same function. Once completed, exercise recursion and prepare to call itself (beginAnimations) until all ints=5.

-I decided to fade from 1->.5->1 because the .5 alpha was annoying me. Shouldn't be hard to switch that around if you want it reversed.

-To make sure no button fades more than fives times, you need to declare and increment an int corresponding to each button.

-Use arc4random(), not random(). Random is for debugging as you will have the same result every time.

-Keep your switch case's straight; was hard to understand what you wanted to be different between them. On this note, use breaks and a default statement! Good luck employing all this into your app.

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    //declare and define button specifics
    btnYellow = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnYellow setBackgroundColor: [UIColor yellowColor]];
    btnYellow = [self buttonTraits:btnYellow];
    [btnYellow setFrame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 30)];
    [btnYellow setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnYellow.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    btnRed = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnRed setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
    [btnRed setFrame: CGRectMake(20, 60, 280, 30)];
    [btnRed setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnRed.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    btnBlue = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnBlue setFrame: CGRectMake(20, 100, 280, 30)];
    [btnBlue setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnBlue.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    [btnBlue setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
    btnGreen = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnGreen setFrame: CGRectMake(20, 140, 280, 30)];
    [btnGreen setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnGreen.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    [btnGreen setBackgroundColor: [UIColor greenColor]];

    //add buttons to the view
    [self.view addSubview:btnYellow];
    [self.view addSubview:btnRed];
    [self.view addSubview:btnBlue];
    [self.view addSubview:btnGreen];

    //set the counting ints to 0
    yellowCount = 0, redCount = 0, blueCount = 0, greenCount = 0;

    //run through the animations the first time
    [self beginAnimations];
}

-(void)beginAnimations
{
    if (!(yellowCount==5 && redCount==5 && blueCount == 5 && greenCount == 5))
    {
        //if you want 5 buttons, define another one, then the next line would be int rand=random()%6;
        int rand=((arc4random()%5)+1); //arc4random gives 0-3; add 1 for 1-4
        switch (rand) {
            case 1:
            {
                //make sure this button hasn't gone through the process 5 times already
                if (yellowCount<5)
                {
                    //increment the button's count
                    yellowCount++;
                    //set up animation with 1.5 second duration (alpha decline from 1->.5)
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                        [btnYellow setAlpha:.5];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
                    {
                        if(finished==TRUE)
                        {
                            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                                [btnYellow setAlpha:1];
                            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                if(finished==TRUE)
                                {
                                    [self beginAnimations];
                                }
                            }];
                        }
                    }];
                }
                else
                {
                    //restart the animation hoping to get another button that hasn't gone 5 times yet
                    [self beginAnimations];
                }
            }
                break; //you forgot a break here. can cause troubles
            case 2:
            {
                if (redCount<5)
                {
                    redCount++;
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^
                    {
                        [btnRed setAlpha:.5];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
                    {
                        if(finished==TRUE)
                        {
                            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                                [btnRed setAlpha:1];
                            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                if(finished==TRUE)
                                {
                                    [self beginAnimations];
                                }
                            }];
                        }
                    }];
                }
                else
                {
                    [self beginAnimations];
                }
            }
                break;
            case 3:
            {
                if (blueCount<5)
                {
                    blueCount++;
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^
                    {
                        [btnBlue setAlpha:.5];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
                    {
                        if(finished==TRUE)
                        {
                            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                                [btnBlue setAlpha:1];
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                if(finished==TRUE)
                                {
                                    [self beginAnimations];
                                }
                            }];
                        }
                    }];
                }
                else
                {
                    [self beginAnimations];
                }
            }
                break; //you forgot another break here. can cause troubles

            case 4:
            {
                if (greenCount<5)
                {
                    greenCount++;
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^
                    {
                        [btnGreen setAlpha:.5];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
                    {
                        if(finished==TRUE)
                        {
                            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                                [btnGreen setAlpha:1];
                            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                if(finished==TRUE)
                                {
                                    [self beginAnimations];
                                }
                            }];
                        }
                    }];
                }
                else
                {
                    [self beginAnimations];
                }
            }
                break;
            default:
            {
                //in case of an awry number, restart the process (be wary; infinite loop potential)
                [self beginAnimations];
            }
                break; //it is of good practice to always have a default method in switch statements
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //the process is complete
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
    UIButton *btnYellow;
    UIButton *btnRed;
    UIButton *btnBlue;
    UIButton *btnGreen;

    int yellowCount;
    int redCount;
    int blueCount;
    int greenCount;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are setting up the button's alpha to 0.5 and then to 1 immediately, the button's alpha won't animate. You can get an idea this snippet

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [your_btn setAlpha:0.5];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if(finished)
        [self performSelector:@selector(revertAlphaToOne) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}];
```

And in that `revertAlphaToOne` Method, you can revert the button's alpha to 1 as

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [your_btn setAlpha:1.0];
} completion:nil
}];
```

Adjust the time variables according to your likings And/Or call the second snippet in the first block's completion block itself.

Comment: Ive used sleep(1) between the setAlphas. Is this a bad way to implement it if later I want to find out which object is lit up and then what order they are lit up in. Then with this information make a touch event.

Comment: Animation via blocks are the best way to do that. Store button's tag or something like that somewhere to access which button object has been lit up. If you want to change alpha on touch event, send `revertAlphaToOne` method a message with an button's tag. Change the method as `-(void)revertAlphaToOneForButtonWithTag:(int)buttonTag`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in cases 1 and 2, you set the `alpha` value to `0.5` and then IMMEDIATELY back to `1`. So when the animation starts, it is simply `1` and will remain so. Just delete the 2nd assignment, and the animation will change alpha to `0.5`.  PS: As already mentioned, the random number generated is from 0 to 4, and not from 1 to 5.